# Is it possible to change the property of an item type when a schema is imported in HCL OneTest Data?

Tags: regex, import, xsd, schema

When a user imports the schema from XSD, is it possible to change the value of any property such as regular expression, minimum occurrence, or maximum occurrence for the list of items in HCL OneTest Data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can modify the schema in HCL OneTest Data after importing any schema.